# An abelian group of finite order has an element of the order of the group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need a hint or tip for this statatement.

If G is an abelian group of order $ n $, then it has an element of order $ n $.

And what if it is not abelian?

Comment: This is only true for cyclic groups and not all abelian groups are cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group of order $n$ has an element of order $n$ precisely when it is cyclic. Every cylic group is abelian, so a non-abelian group of order $n$ can't have an element of order $n$. However, not every abelian group is cyclic. Consider $C_2\times C_2$, for example (where $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order $2$).